# llvm function wrapper for timing

Tags: llvm, clang

I would like to add a function wrapper in order to record the entry and exit times of certain functions. It seems that LLVM would be a good tool to accomplish this. However, I've been having trouble finding a tutorial on how to write function wrappers. Any suggestions?

p.s. my target language is C

Comment: Can you be more specific. How do you want to use this? Are you working with the llvm C++ API or Clang?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to call `func_start` when entering each function and `func_return` when returning, the easiest way is to do the following:

```
for each function F
  insert a call to func_start(F) before the first instruction in the entry block
  for each block B in function F
    get the terminator instruction T
    if T is a return instruction
      insert a call to func_return(F) before T
```

All in all, including boilerplate code for your `FunctionPass`, wou'll have to write about 40 lines of code for this.

If you really want to go with the wrapper approach you have to do:

```
for each function F
  clone function F (call it G)
  delete all instructions in F
  insert a call to func_start(F) in F
  insert a call to G in F (forwarding the arguments), put the return value in R
  insert a call to func_return(F) in F
  insert a return instruction returning R in F
```

The code complexity in this case will be slightly higher and you'll likely incur in a higher compile- and run-time overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I like doing this and use several approaches, depending on the circumstance.

The easiest if you are on a Linux platform is to use the wonderful ltrace utility. You provide the C program you are timing as an argument to ltrace. The "-T" option will output the elapsed call time. If you want a summary of call times use the "-c" option. You can control the amount of output by using the "-e" and "--library" options. Other platforms have somewhat similar tools (like dtrace) but they are not quite as easy to use.

Another, slightly hackish approach is to use macros to redefine the function names. This has all the potential pitfalls of macros but can work well in a controlled environment for smallish programs. The C preprocessor will not recursively expand macros so you can just call the *actual* function from inside your wrapper macro at the point of call. This avoids the difficulty of placing the "stop timing" code before each potential return in the function body.

```
#define foo(a,b,c) ({long t0 = now(); int retval = foo(a,b,c); long elapsed = now() - t0; retval;})
```

Notice the use of the non-standard code block inside an expression. This avoids collisions of the temporary names used for timing and retval. Also by placing retval as the last expression in the statement list this code will time function calls that are embedded in assignments or other expressional contexts (you need to change the type of "retval" to whatever is appropriate for your function).

You must be very careful NOT to include the #define before prototypes and such.

Use your favorite timer function and its appropriate data type (double, long long, whatever). I like <chrono> in C++11 myself.